# High-level differences between node.js and ZeroMQ?

Tags: comparison, node.js, zeromq

Excuse my ignorance, but what is the high-level overview of (something like) node.js versus ZeroMQ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Node.js is a javascript vm based on V8 -- its built to be a full programming environment for asynchronous IO

ZeroMQ is a library for doing a variety of things -- message queueing over arbitrary protocols. Compatible with AMQP (message protocol) and does not have to have a broker (central routing server).

Basically totally different :-) There is even a half functional binding of ZeroMQ for node http://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node - and a more functional one for amqp in general that ry built - http://github.com/ry/node-amqp